# Is there a way to keep all the object types of each column in a dataframe when converting the dataframe into a matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I would like to convert a dataframe into a matrix in R. The dataframe has more than 30 different variables with different types, some are numeric, some factors and some characters. When converting it into a matrix, I would like to keep all types exactly the same as in the dataframe.

I tried converting it with as.matrix(), see code below (this is just a simple example dataframe with only two variables).

```
test_df <- data.frame(a = c(1:10), b = c(letters[1:10]))
test_df <- as.matrix(test_df)
typeof(test_df[,1])
typeof(test_df[,2])
```

Column 'a' in the example has type integer while column 'b' has type factor. I expect each column to keep its type when converting a dataframe into a matrix. However, when I convert it into a matrix, all variables are being converted into type character.

Comment: i'm curious to know why you are pursuing this? a matrix can only have one type of data. there may be another way to address your needs?

Comment: Because I have to loop through the dataframe which takes a lot of time because it has more than 4 million rows. Looping through matrices is way quicker I noticed. I was hoping that I could convert the dataframe into a matrix, and then loop through it, before converting it back into a dataframe. But from your answer I understand that this is not possible.

Comment: If you show the exact problem with the code you are using, then somebody may be able to help you with a more efficient way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  In R, a matrix has to be all one type: it is stored as a vector of that type together with an attribute saying how many rows and columns it has.

For efficiency, you're right that matrices are a lot faster than dataframes.  Maybe you can split your dataframe into one numeric one and one character one.  Most other types can be coerced to those types without much loss.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this solved my problem!